# JPQL, Where condition on Set with List of values

Tags: jpql

```
@Entity 
public class Person{

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="person" , fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Certificate> certificates;
}


@Entity 
public class Certificate{

    private String courseName;

    @ManyToOne 
    @JoinColumn(name="person_id")
    private Person person;

}
```

Having an entity `class(Person)`, which holds a collection(Set) of related entities(Certificate) mapped using `@OneToMany` as above.
Now I have to fetch `all Persons having certificate.courseName IN ("OCPJP", "OCPWCD").`

In Simple SQL, My query will be like this.

```
select distinct p.firstName, p.lastName from Person p join Certificate c on p.Id = c.person_Id
where c.courseName IN ("OCPJP", "OCPWCD")
```

How to get similar output in JPQL?

Answer (score 1):

Such a query can be written as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(c.person) FROM Certificate c WHERE c.courseName IN (:coursenames)
```

Complete example:

```
List<String> courseNames = Arrays.asList("OCPJP", "OCPWCD");

List<Person> result = em.createQuery(
        "SELECT DISTINCT(c.person) " +
        "FROM Certificate c " +
        "WHERE c.courseName IN (:coursenames)", Person.class)
        .setParameter("coursenames", courseNames)
        .getResultList();
```